# How to create new column in tableau with formula calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I am really new to the tableau. Can someone help out and advise how to create new column inside table with formula calculation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwKY3.png)

Formula: (Answered interactions – Interactions that miss service level) / (Answered interactions + Abandoned interactions + Flow-outs)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to display it on the same sheet if you have [Metric Name] in the view. But you can do it on another sheet and place them side by side on a dashboard.

```
count(if [Metric Name] = 'Answered interactions' then [Count] end)
```

This will isolate just the Answered interactions counts. Follow this pattern for the rest of the formula.